# jQuery - stop propogation when selecting checkbox by input or td

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

I want to toggle a checkbox that is within a td by clicking the td itself (and / or the checkbox).

I have the following code:

```
$("[id^=musicCheckboxHoldingTD]").on("click", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $this = $(this);
    $this.find('.musicSelectionRoundCheckbox:checkbox').click();

});
$(".musicSelectionRoundCheckbox:checkbox").click(function(e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
     $this = $(this);
     musicCheckboxToggled($this); // this function gets called twice 
});
```

When I click only the td this works perfectly.

If I click the checkbox within the td then the function gets called twice due to an event for the td AND an event for the checkbox.

How do I prevent this happening to only have the function run once?

Thanks :-)

Comment: Works just fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/w13ocdt8/ I replace your func by `alert` and never get alert twice.

Comment: @tuananh strange? Will recheck this tonight when I get home from work. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need two events ? From what i see, having just the event on the td without stoping the propagation would allow you to have an handler for your checkbox + td.

```
$("#musicCheckboxHoldingTD").on("click", function (e) {
    musicCheckboxToggled($(this));
});
```

If your td have other thing that should not be triggering the event, you can tune the selector and prevent propagation.

```
$("#musicCheckboxHoldingTD, #musicCheckboxHoldingTD > input[type=checkbox]").on("click", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    musicCheckboxToggled($(this));
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I don't need two events so will try your first answer tonight when I get home from work. If it works I'll mark this as accepted answer. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of trouble with this and it seems that the browser was 'checking' the checkbox and then my jquery event was reversing that.

I ended up disabling the checkbox by putting `disabled="disabled"` in line with the HTML input element.

Then I used the following jQuery code:

```
$("[id^=musicCheckboxHoldingDiv]").on("click", function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation(); // stop the event bubble up
    $this = $(this);
    var obj =$this.find('input');    
    obj.prop('checked', !obj.is(':checked'));  
    musicCheckboxToggled();    

 });
```

This is working at the moment. If anyone can see any issues with this answer then let me know in the comments or improve on it with another answer. I'll leave it a few days and then mark this as the accepted answer otherwise.

Thanks for everyones help :-)